# 2D character is not moving in Unity, using the keys. Script seems to be correct. Please verify the code and the Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

![This is how my Inspector looks like]([inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Fp0.png))

And here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 Movement = Vector2.zero;
        Movement.y = v;
        Movement.x = h;

        transform.Translate(Movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

} // class
```

And no, increasing the speed to check if its just not moving really slow, did not help :(

Comment: Your script looks correct. Throwing stuff at the wall here, but maybe try printing out the value of `h` and `v` in the frame update loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set correct value in inspector or in start funciton.

```
void Start()
{
    speed = 10f;
}
```

[inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xUB0.png)

Comment: Nope. Didnt work yet after following your tip.